# what is cPath in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

In my wordpress .htaccess file there is one Rewrite condition there is cPath. I want to know the meaning of cPath and why use this in cPath?

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]
```

Comment: The title is a way to sumarize the question. The question should be readable without reading the title. Even if I would edit the title in, it would be helpful if you copy/pasted the entire rule, not just a condition of one rule.

Answer (score 0):

That is part of a regex and has no special meaning so it just matches the string `cPath` in the URL.